# creating a tableviewcontroller of contacts sorted with indexes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

hello i am new to IOS dev, and i need to create the contacts like view, i was able to create it if i already have the arrays of contacts and indexes, but what i need is the get the contacts from the server and sort them with indexes with objective C, any help?

i checked this tutorial:

```
     animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
                    @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
                    @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
                    @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
                    @"G" : @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"],
                    @"H" : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"],...
sectionTitles = [[animals allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    animalIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];
```

but obviously this isn't what i need,

Answer (score 0):

First you have to sort all keys :

```
NSArray *keys = [animals allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = [someDictionary objectForKey:a];
    NSString *second = [someDictionary objectForKey:b];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

after sorting keys you have to sort each array against keys .

```
for( i= 0 ; i < [sortedKeys count ]; i++){
NSArray * arr = [animals objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex: i] ];
NSArray *sortedArray = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
return [[obj1 valueForKey:@"value"] compare:[obj2 valueForKey:@"value"]];
}];
```